# c++ const use. can i remove it?

Tags: c++, constants

i want to implement a fast random generator, and i came across this site : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift, where is proposed the following code

```
#include <stdint.h>

/* The state must be seeded so that it is not everywhere zero. */
uint64_t s[2];

uint64_t xorshift128plus(void) {
    uint64_t x = s[0];
    uint64_t const y = s[1];
    s[0] = y;
    x ^= x << 23; // a
    s[1] = x ^ y ^ (x >> 17) ^ (y >> 26); // b, c
    return s[1] + y;
}
```

i was wondering if const here has any use and can i remove it safely?

Comment: This is C. Do not trust the phrase "C/C++".

Comment: Yes you can, why do you think you could not? And why do you want to remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `const` here prevents `y` from being accidentally modified; for example if the programmer had accidentally mistyped the `x` in the fourth statement as `y` (`y ^= x << 23`) the compiler would have complained.

You can remove it with no semantic effect on the program as is, but I don't see why you would want to.

Comment: i am transferring this to c# where consts have a more strict use. i was just surprised to see it and wondering if i was missing something. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `const`, but you should not to do this.

Actually, `const` variables states that the variable cannot be changed. If you try to change, then you cannot compile it. If the variable change will cause logical error for the program , we prevent it by using `const` variable.